# How to build a simple NFC based Android app, read only

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, nfc

Here's a loaded question for you guys.  First off, what background I have is in Visual Studio 2010 and C#.  I have all the code as far as SQL queries and such already written in a PC variant of this application.  I haven't made an Android app before, and I don't have experience with java.  I'm just praying it isn't too far a leap from C#.

What I want to do is make a very basic app which would be called when the NFC scanned a tag.  The app would then push the contents of the tag to an SQL database.  There doesn't need to be much, if any, user interface.

As of right now, I've installed the Eclipse IDE with the Android SDK.  I went through the tutorial and made the Hello World app then ran it on my device (Nexus 4 running stock 4.2.1).

I've been trying to find tutorials and such, but I need something fairly basic as I'm not familiar with this environment yet.  Any pointers on where to start or how to go about making this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To get started with the NFC app creation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

some tutorials for working with SQL databases:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android